# Webpack 3 - ExtractTextPlugin - localIdentName not applying to component from node_modules

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, extract-text-plugin, webpack-3

I have a Webpack 3 setup using `ExtractTextPlugin`, and the `localIdentName` is not applying to the CSS classes generated from `node_modules`, specifically from the `react-spinkit` package.

I am using a `<Spinner />` component from `react-spinkit`, which is producing the following CSS class:[image: chrome screenshot]
You'll see that the classes imported by the module are clearly not having the `localIdentName` hash applied to them.

`ExtractTextPlugin` seems to be generating the classnames properly, as demonstrated in my `app.css` output file:
[image]

Webpack is always making me learn how it works every time I use it. Here is my configuration file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    modules: ['node_modules', 'app'],
    alias: {
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/assets')
    }
  },

  entry: {
    app: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      './src/client.tsx'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./build/public'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    pathinfo: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      loader: 'tslint-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      loader: 'react-hot-loader!awesome-typescript-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              modules: true
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }),
    },
    {
      test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=1000&name=images/[hash].[ext]'
    }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CheckerPlugin(),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: '../manifest.json'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true),
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Thanks for the input in advance!